# Semantic UI React - floated button coming out of its container?

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm using Semantic UI React.  I have a Segment component with a few things inside, ending with a Button that I want to float right, but when I float it right it starts coming out of the Segment:

[image: floated button is outside segment]

If I don't float it, it stays inside the Segment nicely, but it's on the left, and I want it on the right:

[image]

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `float`, try using `margin-left:auto`. This will align a block level element on the right of its container.

Comment: This worked, but only after I also added `display: inherit`.  Apparently the Semantic UI framework adds classes of `.ui.button` to Button components, and those classes get set to `display: inline-block` which apparently ignores the `margin-left: auto` setting.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of manually adjusting CSS rules, you can simply set `clearing` on the `Segment`, which, as [the documentation](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/segment/) confirms, clears floated content.

Under the hood, it currently appears to apply a variant of the clearfix:

```css
.ui.clearing.segment::after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U need use some like

```
button{
float:right;
position:inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was studying an Angular book and saw that they added this css in the standard styles.css to get the button inside the segment:

```
form.form:after {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

This helps me to get the button inside the form and use the right floated classes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution using only Semantic instead of custom CSS.
Simply put the button in another container and set the alignment on the container:

```
 <div class="ui right aligned container">
     <button class="ui button" type="submit">Add All</button>
 </div>
```